# Android Shader gradient with background colour

Tags: java, android, textview, gradient

I'm trying to make a TextView filled by a gradient.But my gradient is composed of 2 layers:

- a background colour (#FF8310)
- a gradient from #FF8310 to #FDC830 and the second colour have 60% opacity.

[image]

For the moment I have the following code to make the gradient text view :

```java
TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
TextPaint paint = myTextView.getPaint();
float width = paint.measureText(String.valueOf(myTextView.getText()));
Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, myTextView.getTextSize(),
    new int[]{
        Color.parseColor("#FF8310"),
        Color.argb(153, 253, 200, 48) // #FDC830 color with 60% alpha
    }, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
myTextView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

But with this I can't set the background color.
I tried to set a colour to the textview with `setTextColor` but it doesn't work. How can I add a colour background to the Shader ? Maybe using LayerDrawable ?